# Does TeamCity have conflicts with XCOPY commands?

Tags: teamcity

My batch file works correctly when I run it directly. It's purpose is to copy a folder and it's content's to another location.

```
@echo off
XCOPY /E "C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp" "C:\Automation Results\Latest\"
```

But when I execute this batch file via TeamCity Command Line, the new folder is created but none of the contents are copied to it. All that shows in the new folder is some 'teamcity' files.

[image: New Folder]

I cannot figure out what is happening here. I created a Powershell TeamCity build step to execute the batch file and it had the same resulting outcome.

I would have assumed that TeamCity solely executed the batch file I point it towards and is not concerned what is inside the batch file! But why then can I run it locally successfully but TeamCity does not bahave in the same way.

Does TeamCity have conflicts with XCOPY commands?

Comment: What are you expecting to be in C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp?

Comment: I use TC to run my automation test suite, so my output folder contains logs and screenshots taken during the test suite run. C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\atester_PC NAME 2014-05-22 16_42_37\Out\. The 'Out' folder contains the logs and screenshots. Each time I run the test suite the TC temp file is over written, so this additional TC configuration step is to backup the results before the next test suite run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeamCity does not conflict with XCopy. At the point the step runs I think it is executing correctly. The files you are expecting are probably not in the folder at that point. The TeamCity files you are seeing are the files from C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp when the step runs.

Comment: To ensure that is not the case: I've tested this by disabling all other TC configuration steps and manually copied a folder (with contents) to the required location. I then run my step via TeamCity and I get the about issue.

Comment: psych you are correct! When I enabled all my build steps again and ran my TC project build properly, this step is working. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Go to my computer properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables...

On the System variables groupbox search for "Path" variable and edit.

At the end of the Variable value add this line:

```
;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
```

This should fix it.